# How to write a custom searcher with ransack?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ransack

I have a table called employees(Employee model), which has a column named "ancestry" of type string (because of the ancestry gem).

Employee's ancestry column looks like "1/2/3". '3' is the direct Parent of the employee, '2' is the parent of '3', and '1' is the parent of '2'. It's very intuitive.

I have a custom ransack searcher defined in my `/app/models/employee.rb` model to get only the descendants of an employee, but not the employee itself that looks like this.

```
  ransacker :managers_ids, type: :integer do
    Arel.sql("replace(employees.ancestry, '/', ' ')")
  end
```

and then, in my  `config/initializers/ransack.rb` i have a custom predicate to send an array as params in my URL, to search in my DB that looks like this.

```
Ransack.configure do |config|
  config.add_predicate 'special_in',
    arel_predicate: 'matches_regexp',
    # Converts string array into array and join with | that are OR in regex SQL
    formatter: proc { |v| "#{JSON.parse(v).join("|")}"},
    type: :array
end
```

All this works very well to filter my `/employees` endpoint like `/employees?q[managers_ids_special_in][]=1&q[managers_ids_special_in][]=2` and get all the descendants of managers(parents) whose id's are '1' and '2'. But i get only the descendants.

What i want to achieve is to get the descendants AND the manager itself, but i can't seem to understand how to modify my custom ransacker search filter to achieve this. I know i have to add something like `employees.id` in my managers_ids ransacker, but i just can't figure it out. Thanks in advance for any help i can get, I am so very stuck at this problem..

Comment: have you tried using a compound ransack predication like `managers_ids_special_in_or_id_in`?

Comment: As an aside this is probably not the best way to perform this match for example as your dataset grows the ancestry column may store values like "1/212" based on your current pattern matching 1, 2, 21, 12, and 212 will all match when compared to this String.

Comment: @engineersmnky You are spot on about the problem with ancestry... i'm trying to fix it right now even. Any ideas? i'm trying different arel predicates but none will work out of the box. About the Compound predication, i ""solved it"" by using a SQL UNION. Basically i just get my filtered_collection, and then i use UNION to concatenate the "managers" objects (i used active_record_extended gem for this).